# combine 2 variables with a line break and insert into table

Tags: php

Can someone advise what i'm doing wrong? or if i'm going the wrong way about it?

I want to concatenate 2 strings from 2 textareas and insert them into a column in my table.

this bit of code is from the send message page,

**$msgfull** is the message that the user wishes to send,
**$msqquote** is the message the user is replying to (displayed in a read only textarea)

```
$recipient= $_POST['sendto'];
$subjectmsg= $_POST['subject'];
$msgfull= $_POST['messagetext'];
$msgquote= $_POST['replyquote'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$replyupdate = $msgfull."\n".$msgquote;
```

I want to insert $replyupdate into the table.

It works how it is, BUT, it doesn't give me the line break, it just puts it all into one line.

on the View Message page, I want $msgfull to show first, then a line break (or 2) then the $msgquote (original message) to be displayed.

Can anyone advise please?

Note: I am aware of the security issues on my POST data, They are old scripts I am amending and slowly removing all the mysql commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while displaying the string, use `nl2br` function which converts all `\n` chars to `<br />`

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. after reading about the function, I understand that whilst I was adding the \n correctly in the sendmessage page, I wasn't using the echo nl2br function in the view message page.

Thankyou sir.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
$replyupdate = $msgfull."<br />".$msgquote;
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a function `nl2br` used for this purpose if I am not wrong !

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't display `\n` linefeeds since they are only used to structure the html, not the resulting page.
That is what the `<br>` tag is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply HTML break tag also

```
$replyupdate = $msgfull."<br />".$msgquote;
```

This will give what you are expecting

Comment: hello, the <br /> didnt work. it simply displayed the <br /> in the view message as text.

someone posted, then deleted, and option of \r\n . This worked exactly how I wanted it to. it adds a line break now.

can someone tell me why this works but none of the others do?

I am recalling the table data into a textarea using this:

`<p><? echo bb($fetchmail->message); ?></p>`  (bb being the script for smileys, bold font etc)

Comment: This will work wherever you use in HTML structure. I worked out and then only i posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing HTML you need to use `<br>` instead of `\n`. If you are storing your string in a table you can use `nl2br` function.